# How to use not function for complex child element in xpath

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, wso2, xquery

I have message like below i wish to remove the Response_OutputData Tag .
I have  used xpath not function but it seems not function magic is not working on this

### my input

```
 <open:reponce xmlns:open="http://www.openuri.org/">
         <env:hjEnvelope xmlns:env="http://hj.mn.mw/Envelope">
            <env:UserId>as</env:UserId>
            <env:Sender>as</env:Sender>
            <env:MessageId>22195544</env:MessageId>
            <env:CorrelationId>1</env:CorrelationId>
            <env:GenTimeStamp>1</env:GenTimeStamp>
            <env:SentTimeStamp>1</env:SentTimeStamp>
            <env:Payload>
               <MOP xmlns="http://hj.mn.mw/MOP" xmlns:ns2="http://www.openuri.org/">
                  <Response>
                     <Result_OutputData>
                        <resultCode>0</resultCode>
                        <reference_ID>90</reference_ID>
                     </Result_OutputData>
                     <Response_OutputData>
                        <SystemName>google</SystemName>
                        <InterfaceName>nip</InterfaceName>
                        <ResultCode>0</ResultCode>
                        <ResultMessage/>
                        <ReferenceID>90</ReferenceID>
                     </Response_OutputData>
                  </Response>
               </MOP>
            </env:Payload>
         </env:hjEnvelope>
      </open:reponce>
```

My xpath is like this

```
//env:hjEnvelope/*[not(local-name()='Response_OutputData')]
```

But its not working giivng same output as above 
my expected output is

```
<open:reponce xmlns:open="http://www.openuri.org/">
         <env:hjEnvelope xmlns:env="http://hj.mn.mw/Envelope">
            <env:UserId>as</env:UserId>
            <env:Sender>as</env:Sender>
            <env:MessageId>22195544</env:MessageId>
            <env:CorrelationId>1</env:CorrelationId>
            <env:GenTimeStamp>1</env:GenTimeStamp>
            <env:SentTimeStamp>1</env:SentTimeStamp>
            <env:Payload>
               <MOP xmlns="http://hj.mn.mw/MOP" xmlns:ns2="http://www.openuri.org/">
                  <Response>
                     <Result_OutputData>
                        <resultCode>0</resultCode>
                        <reference_ID>90</reference_ID>
                     </Result_OutputData>
                      </Response>
               </MOP>
            </env:Payload>
         </env:hjEnvelope>
      </open:reponce>
```

How would i achive this using xpath is it possible or xquery or xslt
any one clarify this
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Response_OutputData` is not direct child of `hjEnvelope`. Try using double slashes : `//env:hjEnvelope//*[not(local-name()='Response_OutputData')]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can define some empty template for 'Response_OutputData'node like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match ="*[local-name()='Response_OutputData']">
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```